# Adding a tuple to list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I would like add something like this `('first lastname',  [])` to

```
[('Bill Gates', [100, 32, 44]), ('Leonardo Dicaprio', [32, 22, 10]), ('Jeff Bezos', [11, 100, 170])]
```

I have tried this

```
list = [('Bill Gates', [100, 32, 44]), ('Leonardo Dicaprio', [32, 22, 10]), ('Jeff Bezos', [11, 100, 170])]
variable = input('first lastname') # type "John" and hit enter
tuple(variable)
list.append(tuple(variable))
```

I got:

```
[('Bill Gates', [100, 32, 44]), ('Leonardo Dicaprio', [32, 22, 10]), ('Jeff Bezos', [11, 100, 170]), ('J', 'o', 'h', 'n')]
```

What I expected was:

```
[('Bill Gates', [100, 32, 44]), ('Leonardo Dicaprio', [32, 22, 10]), ('Jeff Bezos', [11, 100, 170]), ("John", [])]
```

Comment: refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878470/add-tuple-to-list-of-tuples-in-python

Comment: You add a tuple to a list the same way you add anything else to a list; and the existing contents are also irrelevant to how you do it. I don't actually understand what the supposed difficulty is, or the question. Did you make any attempt to write code? If you did, what went wrong?

Comment: @gretal if you think a question has been asked before, you should vote to close as a duplicate, rather than simply commenting with the reference. That said, the other question is **not** the same, despite its poor title. (If that question were asked today, it would presumably be closed, as it's a) unclear and b) really a synthesis of two questions.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel ('J', 'o', 'h', 'n') that is what is wrong.

Comment: Also, seems like you're relatively new here @VLSI_EE_01! Welcome! Usually, especially with simple questions like "How do I do X", we'd like to see what you've tried before. This could be links you've looked at with explanations of why they didn't help, or code you've written that doesn't work and what you expected as an output if it were to work. If you change those things, you might find your post receives less downvotes, and may actually receive some upvoting too!

Comment: That doesn't tell me the problem. You need to show *exactly* the input, *exactly* the code you tried to use, *exactly* what result you got, *exactly* what result you expect for that input, and explain how it is different.

Comment: @ProQ below is code that I have tried but someone else has already suggested it. List.append only takes one argument. I have also tried this variable = input('first lastname') -> tuple(variable) -> list.append(tuple(variable) -> gives me [('Bill Gates', [100, 32, 44]), ('Leonardo Dicaprio', [32, 22, 10]), ('Jeff Bezos', [11, 100, 170]),  ('J', 'o', 'h', 'n')]

Comment: @VLSI_EE_01 Thanks for the info, I think I understand your question now and can provide a better answer. Please let me know if I didn't edit your question correctly!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct to try to append the variable to the list, but your mistake is in trying to turn the string into a tuple.

Apparently Python will take a string and break it up by character if you try to turn it into a tuple.

That is:

```py
>>> tuple('John')
('J', 'o', 'h', 'n')
```

So, there are two things we can do. If you just want to add `'John'` to the end of the list, you can just append it on its own.

(This is from the interactive interpreter, which you get if you type `python` into a terminal.)

```
>>> list = [('Bill Gates', [100, 32, 44]), ('Leonardo Dicaprio', [32, 22, 10]), ('Jeff Bezos', [11, 100, 170])]
>>> variable = input('first lastname') # type "John" and hit enter
first lastnameJohn
>>> list.append(variable)
>>> list # show the list
[('Bill Gates', [100, 32, 44]), ('Leonardo Dicaprio', [32, 22, 10]), ('Jeff Bezos', [11, 100, 170]), 'John']
```

However, if you want to add the tuple `(John, [])` to the end of the list, you don't have to use the tuple function. Instead, you can just enclose it in parentheses and Python will make it into a tuple like you want without doing anything weird.

That is:

```
>>> list = [('Bill Gates', [100, 32, 44]), ('Leonardo Dicaprio', [32, 22, 10]), ('Jeff Bezos', [11, 100, 170])]
>>> variable = input('first lastname') # type "John" and hit enter
first lastnameJohn
>>> list.append((variable, []))
>>> list # show the list
[('Bill Gates', [100, 32, 44]), ('Leonardo Dicaprio', [32, 22, 10]), ('Jeff Bezos', [11, 100, 170]), ('John', [])]
```

In short, I think the code you're looking for is `list.append((variable, []))`.

However, there's one more thing to note, which is that if you're trying to turn a single object into a tuple, you should put parentheses around it, but you have to add a comma just before the final parenthesis to let Python know that you actually want to make a tuple, rather than just put something in parentheses.

For example, if you want to put `'John'` in a tuple, instead of doing `tuple('John')`, you should instead do `('John',)`.

Example:

```
>>> ('John',)
('John',)
```

Comment: Please don't answer in a way that relies on an external link.

Comment: My answer does not rely on an external link. `append` is the function that is being looked for. That is all that is needed. The link is extra.

Comment: Now that you have added the code example, I withdraw my objection.

Comment: I tried something like this variable = input(name) -> tuple(varaible) -> append(tuple)

Comment: @VLSI_EE_01 you can add this information to your question itself so everyone sees it when they look at your question. To do so, edit your question. (If you're having a hard time doing that, feel free to let us know as a comment and we can guide you to the correct resources.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `append` function.

```py
l = [('Bill Gates', [100, 32, 44]), ('Leonardo Dicaprio', [32, 22, 10]), ('Jeff Bezos', [11, 100, 170])]
l.append("first lastname", [])
```

Comment: I'd recommend against using the name `list` because `list` is a pre-defined function in Python that can create a list. I think you should probably use the variable `l` or something similar instead.

Comment: yes thank you, i forgot about that.